# how to set session time out in php?

Tags: php

```
session_cache_expire( 20 );
session_start(); // NEVER FORGET TO START THE SESSION!!!
$inactive = 1200;
if(isset($_SESSION['start']) ) {
    $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['start'];
    if($session_life > $inactive){
        header("Location: user_logout.php");
    }
}
$_SESSION['start'] = time();
if($_SESSION['valid_user'] != true){
header('Location: ../index.php');
}else{
```

I'm making an online examination system. I'm using PHP and MySQL.

I want to set the session time, but don't know how. Please help me.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes

Answer (score 0):

> i am going to set session time

Don't touch it ever.
Default session timeout is good enough for anyone.

You are confusing the session timeout with whatever **application timeout**.

Instead of playing with session timeout you have to store whatever timings in the session itself.
But not to throw a user to login page silently to to warn them gracefully

Comment: This coming from your common sense. You should listen!